# file pattern name for content type

Tags: theming, 8

What is Drupal 8 file pattern name for a specified content type?

Suppose I have  a *Movie* content type. What is the pattern name for its page? Is it `page--node--movie.html.twig`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) is what your looking for.

The Drupal 8 code is the following one.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->getType();
  }
  return $suggestions;
}
```

Comment: vote up. I agree with you, it work

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [same page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) as [ssibal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/58529/ssibal):

> ### Nodes
>
> Pattern: node--[type|nodeid]--[viewmode].html.twig
>
> Base template: node.html.twig (base location: core/modules/node/templates/node.html.twig)
>
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
>   the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:
>
> 1. node--nodeid--viewmode.html.twig
> 2. node--nodeid.html.twig
> 3. node--type--viewmode.html.twig
> 4. node--type.html.twig
> 5. node--viewmode.html.twig
> 6. node.html.twig
>
> Note that underscores in a content type's machine name are replaced by
>   hyphens.
>
> See the [node.html.twig API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!templates!node.html.twig/8).

So for your content type it should be `node--movie.html.twig`